# Probability and Bonferroni Inequality Proof

Tags: probability

If P(E)= 0.9 and P(F) = 0.8, show that P(EF) is greater than or equal to   0.7.

In general, prove Bonferroni’s inequality, namely, for any two events E and F ,
P(EF)>= (P(E) + P(F) - 1).

I generally understand how the Bonferroni inequality works, but I don't know what steps I can take to prove such a thing. What could I write down that PROVES it to be true rather than just gives an example of how it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are familiar with $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)$, your result follows from $P(A\cup B)\le 1$.

Comment: So it's as simple as plugging in solving the equation? If I plug in .8 and .9 in properly and show that it is greater than or equal to .7, it will qualify as a proof? @paw88789

Comment: @user151876: That should work.

Comment: @user151876: By the way, when you get helpful answers, it is good form to upvote them, and accept a good one.  (Actually you need a certain amount of reputation before you can upvote, but you can accept answers.)  I notice that you have not accepted answers to any of your questions to date.